# Can I simply swap out Includes with Indexof in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I'm attempting to debug a JS incompatibility with IE11:

> Object doesn't support property or method 'includes'

I've read that `includes` can easily be replaced with `indexof`. However, as I have very limited JS knowledge I'm not sure if that's the only change I need to make here... Or whether other parts will require rewriting too?

**Original**

```
if (el.method_title.includes('|')){
    el.timeslot = el.method_title.split('|')[1].trim();
    el.method_title = el.method_title.split('|')[0].trim();
}
```

**Proposal**

```
if (el.method_title.indexOf('|')){
```

Comment: `includes()` returns a boolean, `indexOf()` returns a number. You need to change the if function to reflect that: `if (el.method_title.indexof('|') > -1)`

Comment: `.trim` might need rewriting as well when `.includes` is not supported in one of your target environments

Comment: I just implemented the solution from @Strelok and that's exactly the error I got not. Looking into this now.

Comment: You might want to install a polyfill though instead of having to rewrite all of your code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The method is called `indexOf` and will return `-1` if the substring is not found in your string so you should do a comparison:

```
if (el.method_title.indexOf('|') >= 0)
```

The `indexOf()` method returns the position of the first occurrence of a specified value in a string.

This method returns `-1` if the value to search for never occurs.

*Note: The indexOf() method is case sensitive.*

Comment: Everything in JavaScript is case-sensitive :)

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend to not test the string with `includes`/`indexOf` at all - just [`split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) it and check the result:

```
var parts = el.method_title.split('|'); // might want to pass a limit as well
if (parts.length > 1) {
    el.timeslot = parts[1].trim();
    el.method_title = parts[0].trim();
}
```

Simpler and more efficient.